# winforms datagrid change column to combobox on edit

Tags: winforms, datagrid, combobox

I have a datagrid column on my winforms application. When user selects a particular cell, The cell should turn to combobox which is databound, and user is able to edit the cell.

How can I show combobox on editmode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to convert cell into combobox:

this.yourdatagridname.Rows[x].Cells[y] = new DataGridComboBoxCell();

where x,y denotes which cell you want to convert

- In order to make it editable:

this.yourdatagridname.Rows[x].Cells[y].ReadOnly = false;

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in the EditingControlShowing event?

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
 BindingSource bindingSource = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource;
 Person person = bindingSource.Current as Person;
 BindingList<personType> bindingList = this.FindPersonTypes(person);

 DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
 comboBox.DataSource = bindingList;
}
```

Ref: http://www.timvw.be/2007/01/17/exploring-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-databinding/